# SyntaxError python 2.7.13

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo este error al ejecutar este script en python  2.7.13:

```
name = event.name
if len(name) > 1:
    # not a character, special key (e.g ctrl, alt, etc.)
    # uppercase with []
    if name == "space":
        # " " instead of "space"
        name = " "
    elif name == "enter":
        # add a new line whenever an ENTER is pressed
        name = "[ENTER]\n"
    elif name == "decimal":
        name = "."
    else:
        # replace spaces with underscores
        name = name.replace(" ", "_")
        name = f"[{name.upper()}]"
# finally, add the key name to our global `self.log` variable
self.log += name
```

El error es el siguiente:

> ```
> name = f"[{name.upper()}]"
>                          ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Alguien me puede ayudar con este *sytnax error* por favor. También, alguien me puede decir porque me salta muchas veces este tipo de errores y como evitarlos o corregirlos.

Mil gracias a todos.

Comment: Onion, leyendo más detenidamente veo que no es forma de formular una pregunta con el útimo párrafo. No estas en tu casa y pienso que no son formas. Sé cual es tu error pero te pido antes que respetes el idioma del sitio y la formules correctamente para poder ayudarte

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aprende a usar el sitio. Donde dice respuestas, van solo respuestas. Si tenes comentarios a una publicacion, va donde dice comentarios.

Comment: ....y si una respuesta soluciona el problema clicka en el tick verde para aceptarla. Si no, al tiempo el bot de la comunidad la reflota de nuevo porque piensa que ninguna respuesta fue valida para el autor de la pregunta y se queda "huerfana"

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que estás usando python 2.7 y los "f-strings" no se incorporaron hasta la version 3.6 en adelante, por lo que no puedes usar la forma `f""` y aparte la sintaxis de python2 y python3 cambió un poco, pero lo suficiente para que tutoriales y codigo escrito para ambas versiones sean incompatibles.

Te aconsejaría que te pasaras a python 3 puesto que la versión 2 ya ha dejado de tener soporte desde el 1 de enero de 2021 y solo queda para proyectos que no han hecho el cambio todavia.

Si por necesidad tienes que seguir usando python2, la solución seria utilizar su sintaxis pero en realidad no estás formateando nada de la variable `name` asi que simplemente asignar

```
name = name.upper()
```

debería ser suficiente porque `name` ya es un string